# YQL xpath get all text combined from <span> with <strong> inside

Tags: xml, xpath, yql

The xml looks like this

```
<span>one
  <strong>two</strong>
  three
</span>
```

And this is the xpath to the span element

```
AND xpath="//div[@class='detail-body']/div[@class='row detail-footer']/div[@class='col-sm-12 col-md-10']/div/p/span"
```

Everything works great but is there a way to return the result in one string. Basically getting rid of the strong element so the result would look like this (or just as plain text)?

```
<span>one two three</span>
```

The problem with the result I'm getting is when I parse the xml in php using SimpleXML_Load_String I only get the text of the span element without the text from strong.

Comment: you could get `one two three`, without the tags

Comment: how exactly? i tried using text() but it just shows the text from the span

Comment: with `//text()`

Comment: Nice it works! But now the results from all the spans are showing in one line. Is it possible to seperate the results to not show all in one string?